# Given a string, how do I use JQuery to add a class to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var s = '<button class=​"add_friend_action btn success">​abc​</button>';
```

How do I add a class "mini" to this?

`$(s).addClass('mini')` does not work...when I `console.log(s)`, it returns back to normal.

Comment: Do you want to get back an altered string or an actual element (or jQuery object)?

Comment: `$(s).addClass('mini')` works, but it doesn't modify `s`.  You need to save it to a variable `s = $(s).addClass('mini')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assure you, `$(s).addClass('mini')` works just fine. Try this:

```
var s = '<button class=​"add_friend_action btn success">​abc​</button>';
var $temp = $(s).addClass('mini');
console.log($temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

> $(s).addClass('mini') does not work...when I console.log(s), it returns back to normal

That's because strings are immutable, you need to output the html of $(s) to a new string to get the added class.

```
$('<div>').append($(s).addClass('mini')).html();
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with strings being immutable. No part of the code is * intended* to change the string, so immutable strings are tangentially related at best.

Comment: I suppose but he was expecting his original string variable to have been manipulated which isn't happening.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery in this sense is used to manipulate elements after they are already a part of the DOM, and since 's' is, at this point just a string, jQuery won't see it as something that can have a class.

So there are a couple of different way you can accomplish this, the easiest might be to give you string up there an attribute that you can use to target it (or just use the one that is there) and in your doc ready ( or after this element has been created if it isn't on the initial DOM completion) for example:

```
$('elementTargetName').addClass('mini');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Or just do what Matt Ball said. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the string itself, this would be a way: http://jsfiddle.net/AHH5G/1/.

```
var s = '<button class="add_friend_action btn success">abc</button>';

s = $(s).addClass("mini").wrap("<div>").parent().html();
```

Basically, you parse it, add a class, then get the "outer" HTML by wrapping it and calling `.html()` on the wrapper element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var bt = $("<button/>").addClass("add_friend_action btn success mini").text("abc");
```